# How can I get the number of devices connected through the phones access-point?

Tags: java, android

As you all know, Android devices come with the the functionality to turn the phone into a access-point/hotspot.

Is it programatically possible to get the number of devices connected to the phone's wifi access-point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can count connected devices on access point and it's get hardware mac address on below link on android:
http://www.flattermann.net/2011/02/android-howto-find-the-hardware-mac-address-of-a-remote-host/

code from above link:

```
/**
 * Try to extract a hardware MAC address from a given IP address using the
 * ARP cache (/proc/net/arp).<br>
 * <br>
 * We assume that the file has this structure:<br>
 * <br>
 * IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
 * 192.168.18.11    0x1         0x2         00:04:20:06:55:1a     *        eth0
 * 192.168.18.36    0x1         0x2         00:22:43:ab:2a:5b     *        eth0
 *
 * @param ip
 * @return the MAC from the ARP cache
 */
public static String getMacFromArpCache(String ip) {
    if (ip == null)
        return null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4 && ip.equals(splitted[0])) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];
                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    return mac;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or if u have problem on code try below code:

```
 public ArrayList<InetAddress> getConnectedDevices(String YourPhoneIPAddress) {
        ArrayList<InetAddress> ret = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();

        LoopCurrentIP = 0;

        String IPAddress = "";
        String[] myIPArray = YourPhoneIPAddress.split("\\.");
        InetAddress currentPingAddr;


        for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
            try {

                // build the next IP address
                currentPingAddr = InetAddress.getByName(myIPArray[0] + "." +
                        myIPArray[1] + "." +
                        myIPArray[2] + "." +
                        Integer.toString(LoopCurrentIP));
                ad = currentPingAddr.toString();   /////////////////
                Log.d("MyApp",ad);                 //////////////

                // 50ms Timeout for the "ping"
                if (currentPingAddr.isReachable(50)) {

                    ret.add(currentPingAddr);
                    ad = currentPingAddr.toString();        /////////////////
                    Log.d("MyApp",ad);                     //////////////
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }

            LoopCurrentIP++;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I set up my phone's AP and connected my laptop to the AP. When I executed, `cat /proc/net/arp`, I saw one record containing the MAC and IP of my laptop which was correct. The issue is that when I disconnected my laptop from the AP, the ARP cache doesn't refresh and executing the previous command still yeilds one record.

Comment: While your solution sounds legitimate and I was thinking on those lines too, it does have the edge case that a device might not respond to ICMP requests i.e. ping. While this method would work most of the time, it cannot be considered entirely robust. I appreciate your input though. Upvote.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser i used same code but once device is connected it remains in the list till i make hotspot off Due to which i am getting false count 
is there any other way to get updated values in the same file or after how much time the file gets updated (/proc/net/arp)
how to refresh the same file to read latest connected device list