# latest connected device list android hotspot

Tags: android, arp, hotspot

I used the following code to read the connected device ip address[How can I get the number of devices connected through the phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419847/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-devices-connected-through-the-phones-access-point)
but i am getting false list i.e. list shows earlier devices which were connected to hotspot and currently disconnected.
is there any other way to get updated list. or how to refresh the /proc/net/arp file to get the latest list

also read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/765380/when-do-stale-arp-entries-become-failed-when-never-used) which is related to arp on linux but don't find the way out.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me it will show no of devices connected and their mac address

```
 public int getClientList() {
    int macCount = 0;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String flushCmd = "sh ip -s -s neigh flush all";
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        runtime.exec(flushCmd, null, new File("/proc/net"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            if (splitted != null) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];
                System.out.println("Mac : Outside If " + mac);
                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    macCount++;
               /* ClientList.add("Client(" + macCount + ")");
                IpAddr.add(splitted[0]);
                HWAddr.add(splitted[3]);
                Device.add(splitted[5]);*/
                    System.out.println("Mac : " + mac + " IP Address : " + splitted[0]);
                    System.out.println("Mac_Count  " + macCount + " MAC_ADDRESS  " + mac);
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Mac_Count  " + macCount + "   MAC_ADDRESS  "
                                    + mac, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
           /* for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
                System.out.println("Addressssssss     "+ splitted[i]);*/

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return macCount;
}
```

Try this out